Internal Server Error with api calls in R
I have the following function in R to GET a response from Api calls from my website
get_results <- function(headers, experiment_id, ontology = "all") {
  get_drugs_for_results <- function(gene_prioritization) {
    cat("Extracting drugs for gene prioritization...\n")
    print(gene_prioritization)  # Debug: Inspect gene_prioritization content
    
    top_genes <- gene_prioritization$top_genes_configuration
    gene_symbols <- sapply(top_genes, function(x) x$gene_symbol)
    gene_symbols <- unique(gene_symbols)
    cat("Gene symbols to query for drugs:\n")
    print(gene_symbols)  # Debug: Print the gene symbols being queried
    
    response <- GET(
      paste0(url, "drugs"),
      add_headers(.headers = headers),
      query = list(genes = toJSON(gene_symbols))
    )
    cat("Response status code for drugs API:", status_code(response), "\n")
    
    if (status_code(response) == 200) {
      results <- fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content))
      return(results$genesDrugs)
    } else {
      cat("Error in drugs API response:", status_code(response), content(response, "text"), "\n")
      return(list())
    }
  }
  
  cat("-- Results of experiment with ID: ", experiment_id, " --\n")
  
  # Inspect headers and experiment_id before the request
  cat("Headers:\n")
  print(headers)
  cat("Experiment ID:\n")
  print(experiment_id)
  
  response <- GET(paste0(url, "results"),
              add_headers(.headers = headers),
              query = list(experimentId = experiment_id))
  
  cat("Response status code for results API:", status_code(response), "\n")
  cat("Response content:\n")
  print(content(response, "text"))  # Debug: Print raw response content for inspection
  
  if (status_code(response) == 200) {
    results <- fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content))
    status <- results$status
    cat("Experiment status:", status, "\n")
    
    
results <- get_results(headers, experiment_id, ontology)

I am trying to solve the following error :
>     No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
>     Error in results API response: 500 Internal Server Error

The url to the server and all headers(Content-Type:                  "application/json", api-key :"your-api-key"), experiment id ("1234567890") are correct but something is wrong with GET response ? Can you help ?
